# Problem with processing large(>1 GB) CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a large **CSV file** and I have to sort and write the sorted data to another csv file. The CSV file has `10 columns`. Here is my code for sorting.

```
data = [ x.strip().split(',') for x in open(filename+'.csv', 'r').readlines() if x[0] != 'I' ]

data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[6], x[7], x[8], int(x[2])))

with open(filename + '_sorted.csv', 'w') as fout:
    for x in data:
        print(','.join(x), file=fout)
```

It works fine with file size below `500 Megabytes` but cannot process files with a size greater than `1 GB`. Is there any way I can make this process memory efficient? I am running this code on `Google Colab`.

Comment: Why not use the `pandas.read_csv()` function? It should perform the same as your loop for importing in data.

Comment: Can you provide an example with a code? Let's say I've loaded the `CSV` file with `pandas.read_csv`. Then how can I sort this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Link](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/) to a blog about using pandas for large datasets. In the examples from the link, they are looking at analyzing data from large datasets ~1gb in size.

Simply type the following to import your csv data into python.

```
import pandas as pd
gl = pd.read_csv('game_logs.csv', sep = ',')
```